# Cannot access Django administrator site in Django-3

Tags: python, django

Successfully created an admin user using `py manage.py createsuperuser`. Entered username, e-mail, password but whenever I try to access this link http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ it says "This site can’t be reached" and "127.0.0.1 refused to connect, " How do I fix this error and access the administrator site ?

I'm using Windows 10 with the latest version of Django.

before accessing admin page

[image]

Now as soon as I access the admin page (you can see I've put the URL in the address bar) the server stops automatically. See the image below you'll find the page loading but the server automatically quit itself.

[image]

Comment: I'm using windows it says "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: run `python manage.py runserver` from the root of your project (the same folder where `manage.py` is)

Comment: that's what i did before it did not work

Comment: Try `localhost:8000/admin`.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked, can u write this as an answer instead of comment ?

Comment: You can also try python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: why localhost:8000/admin is working and http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin is not ?

Comment: well I don't why now this  "localhost:8000/admin"  is not working

Comment: Post the code of your urls.py file

Comment: Pls check the code of urls.py I think its fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit your root directory (having manage.py file)

```
python manage.py check
```

if no errors

```
python manage.py runserver
```

make sure you access admin site at `localhost:8000/admin/` and your server keeps on running.

**EDIT :**
If you are facing this issue in **Django version-3**, then it is a issue reported [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31092) and [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31067) you need to switch to **python version 3.8** or either **downgrade your django.**

Comment: I ran python manage.py check there were no issues. For the first time when I run python manage.py runserver it works but then afterwards whenever I try to access localhost:8000/admin/ the page does not shows up

Comment: can u attach image what shows up when u access + terminal server output when you hit  localhost:8000/admin/

Comment: kindly check now Ive inserted the images

Comment: the point is your server is stopped in image 2 when you are trying to access admin. Don't quit it, it should be running all the time you are working

Comment: Yes that's the problem I don't know why the server quits itself automatically. I can access my app but whenever I'm trying to access admin the server is quitting itself.

Comment: yes, my Django version is 3.0.4 and Python version is 3.7.0. I went through those links thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

make sure you have the root to your admin page! in the main folder to your project, enter to urls.py

Answer (score 0):

try *localhost:8000/admin/login*
It is what finally logged me in as an admin despite having all my URL paths and admin app activated in my Django project, and when *localhost:8000/admin/* wasn't working. all the best.